# I want to stop page redirect and just add to the url string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just want to make my browser stop redirect.
I have an app working like google drive. I want that when I click a folder at a TreeNav, it only adds to the url and doesn't redirect.

Eg.
from "/home" to "/home/folder1/folder2" with no redirect.

I already have the files for each folder fetched at first load so i just need a way to manipulate the url without redirect and change the files shown in the filebox when at a current directory.

Comment: search for "js change history" and you will find your answer.

Comment: See: [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example